# save csv to array javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

So im trying to join an array so i can save the string as csv.
It works but im getting extra quotes and columns showing up in the csv file, how do i fix my problem.

```
var arr = ["Merry, Christmas", "Halloween", "New Years", "other"]

var quotedAndCommaSeparated = "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";
```

After saving the string to a csv file, there is 2 problems.

There is 2 double quotes, one at the beginning and end of the line in csv.
The first string in array is also getting separated into 2 columns since it has a comma.

Comment: first is 2 words making up one array element. Need to do some escaping

Answer (score 0):

The **`CSV`** file format does not work well with single quote `(')` for this you can change your join string  as follow.

```
var arr = ["Merry, Christmas", "Halloween", "New Years", "other"]

var quotedAndCommaSeparated = '"' + arr.join('","') + '"';
console.log(quotedAndCommaSeparated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [spec for a CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), you must use:

- Double Quotes around each item, if they may contain double quotes or commas
- Escape any double quotes within each item by "doubling" the double quotes

```js
var arr = ["Merry, Christmas", "Halloween", "New Years", "Item with \"Double Quoted\" string"];

// Temporary array to store the modified entries in for the CSV
var arrDoubled = [];

// Loop over the original array, and double up the double quotes
// by taking each item in the `arr` array, and doing a global (`g`) replace
// to change all " to ""
arr.forEach(function(item) {
    arrDoubled.push(item.replace(/"/g, '""'));
});

// Use Double Quotes instead of single for the CSV
// Note that '"' is the same as "\"" (each is a string with a single double quote as contents)
var quotedAndCommaSeparated = "\"" + arrDoubled.join("\",\"") + "\"";

console.log(quotedAndCommaSeparated);
```